# Save emails w/same subject line

Tags: windows-10

I am saving emails from Outlook to my computer file.  When there are emails w/the same subject line, I am given the choice to either 1) copy and replace or 2) leave the email in Outlook.  How can I save emails with the same subject line to my computer file?

Comment: Welcome Linn. Can you provide some screenshots of what you are seeing?